# How to finish java.exe process in applet?

Tags: java, process, applet, java-native-interface

There is an applet on a HTML page. That applet loads a dll library and communicates with an external application through it. I can successfully load and work with that library. That library has functions `INIT()` and `DEINIT()`.

The issue is when I try to call those functions again, the external app/library says that there is only one process can access to that app. It is an internal check. So I need a way to stop the Java process in order to start the app once again. But if I start the applet once, the Java process doesn't finished until I close the browser tab (or even the whole browser).

Is there a way to stop the Java process in the scope of the browser tab? And I need Java to start as soon as applet in the HTML page will appear.

Comment: Do you call DEINIT() when the applet is destroyed?

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg  That is a very good question that (if implemented) would most likely solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop the JVM from the applet, it's managed by the browser.

You might consider switching to a Java Web Start application instead, it's started in its own VM.